# Is calling std::copy from multiple threads for different ranges of the same vector safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

I am computing `float`s from multiple threads and storing the results in non-overlapping ranges of the the same `vector<float>` as follows:

Before running any of the threads I pre-allocated it using `vector::reserve`.

In each thread a thread-specific `vector` of results is computed and then copied into the target container like this:

```
vector<float>::iterator destination = globalVector.begin() + threadSpecificIndex;
std::copy( localVector.begin(), localVector.end(), destination );
```

Is this a safe practice?

Comment: `std::vector::reserve` won't do, you need to actually `resize()` – otherwise you'll be writing beyond the actual `end()` of the vector.

Comment: To add to @mindriot comment: If the type you are storing doesn't have a default constructor you could use something like `boost::optional` instead of your type directly.  This would have added benefit that you can tell if something failed without having to create one of those 'not yet real' objects that don't fully construct themselves.  Those are abominations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First `vector::reserve` doesn't actually create any elements.  It just sets the the capacity of the vector.  If you need the elements to be there you need `vector::resize` or just construct the vector to the size needed.

Secondly the rule of thumb is if you have a shared object between threads and at least one of them is a writer you need synchronization.  Since in this case the "object" is the iterator range and they do not overlap you are okay in this regard.  As long as the vectors size is not changed then you should be okay.

One issue you could have with this is false sharing.  If the same cache line contains variables that different threads are using then those cache lines have to re-synchronized every time a variable in the line is updated.  This can slow down the performance of the code quite a bit.

Comment: Good point about cache. I wonder if any other container would fit better here, but guess that even with this cache thing, vector is the fastest one.

Comment: @piotrsmaron vector is normally the better option.  As long as the range of iterators is larger than a cache line the false sharing should not be an issue.  I just mentioned it as a potential pitfall and I have seen it on small ranges.

Comment: @jaggedSpire No problem.  Thank you for the grammar review.

Comment: @piotrsmaron So basically if you about performance you'll try to hand chunks out in cache line sizes. That is for all practical purposes 64 byte these days, but you have to make sure to align your memory before starting.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `reserve` with `resize`. I don't worry about false sharing because the destination is much larger than the number of threads: something like 1e6 floats computed by 4-24 threads, each writing to 1/4th - 1/24th consecutive portion of the vector.

Comment: @Michael No problem.  I just wanted to make sure you were aware of that.  A lot of people get burned by it when they first try to do something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If the vector has fixed size (and it seems like it has from your question), and ranges are not overlapping, then:

1. vector won't be reallocated
2. different threads won't access the same memory

thus I don't see any data races here. (But according to 1st comment to your question, you must ensure, that vector has this fixed size when it is used). You can see also "Data Races" section for std::copy: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/

Comment: Unless it is `vector<bool>`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. By vector I meant vector<float>, which author of the question was asking about, but thanks for straightening this out.